# Window Close in Swing Application Problem

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i have build a swing application and there are 3 frames

frame-1 contains button that open frame-2 and frame3.                                             Now when i click on the close on top right corner in either frame 2 or frame 3 ,the whole application closes(frame 1 too closes)

What shall i do to avoid this ?

Comment: Perhaps you have set default close operation to exit (`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`) for frame2/3?

Comment: Did you consider making the 2nd & 3rd frames to be dialogs instead?  It would be more natural to have only a single frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this for the frames you want to close but do not want the whole application to close when you close them:

```
theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: EXIT_ON_CLOSE doesn't just close the application, but stops the JVM, so every application in this JVM is closed, if you use it. Which is, why you should avoid it. Maybe your program is started from another Javaprogram?